# Multiple relationships in Views Contextual Filters

Tags: 7, views

I use Views in every project, and its not that often that I run into a use case like this any more.

In the set up below, I have a Content type with two field collection fields (day guest and evening guest). I want to display the results of both field collection fields on the node, in the same view.

Both field collections share an "E-mail" field, and when a user enters their e-mail field, I want them to see their results, whether they have been added as a day guest, or an evening guest.

Here's the setup...
[image]

When I remove one of the two Contextual filters, the results show for the remaining field, and vice versa. But when both Contextual filters are added, I get no results.

Is there a way to do an AND or OR for Contextual filters?

Or in the Contextual filter options, a way to add multiple relationships like below?

[image]

While I know this is not possible in the default behaviour, it is a good example of what i'm trying to achieve, perhaps someone knows a decent workaround to the issue?

Comment: You was able to found solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this module:  https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filters_or 
it gives you posibility to achive your needs

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.